# Bootstrap switch with ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

Good day, I would like to ask if it is possible to add a ng-click event on bs swtch? Im making an app that is when a bootsrap switch is turned on, a modal dialog will pop up. Can someone please give me an idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing using watcher on the model item.

Same kind of issue was reported on [github]
https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ng-click event with ng-if condition.

Comment: @Muthupirya can you give me a sample demo on this if it is not too much of your time?thanks

Comment: <button ng-click="inviteUser($index+1)", ng-if='memberDetail' >Next    </button>  
<Button ng-click="nextForm ($index+1)", ng-if='msgPage'> Next  </button> Based on ng-if condition the button click event triggers.